# Why are the fixed effects of a panel probit regression inconsistent?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, consistency, sufficient-statistics, link-function

I was taught that a probit with fixed effects would not be consistent because the estimates of a non-linear model with a link function other than the canonical (in this case the logit) are not sufficient statistics. Among other things, Stata will not allow for a fixed effects probit (or clog-log, as a matter of fact).

Why would the consistency of the fixed effects estimator depend on the link function not being the canonical one?

Comment: Related to this question, perhaps you will find the answers in there useful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55316/is-the-mundlak-fixed-effects-procedure-applicable-for-logistic-regression-with-d

Comment: It is a different question, but the notes you linked to in your answer seem promising. I still do not understand why the conditional fixed effects cannot be estimated with a link function other than the logit, though.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/88073) to a related question.